# Lotus Notes : How to Remove a value and replace a new value

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

My Question : How to Remove a value and replace a new value

My Field value inside **InvGSTSummary** :

**Value 1:**

**"- 0%,19291.76,0.00"**

**"SE 0%,1068.39,0.00"**

**"ST 6%,2000.00,120.00"**

The order of the Text List might change everytime,

**Value 2:**

**"SE 0%,1068.39,0.00"**

**"- 0%,19291.76,0.00"**

**"ST 6%,2000.00,120.00"**

[image: InvGSTSummary]

**Sample formula i write for testing as below :**

**InvGSTSumCode = @Word(InvGSTSummary; ","; 1)**

[image]

1. The question is May i know how to take the First 2 character is **"SE"** to
   amend the last 3 value become by (using 1068.39 * 6%=64.1034), than
   replace the last 3 value become 64.1034

Final Result For the value should be :

**"- 0%,19291.76,0.00"**

**"SE 0%,1068.39,64.10"**

**"ST 6%,2000.00,120.00"**

**New Update item: on 08/07/2019**

[image: sample]

Sorry may be my question not clear. Actually what i want to ask is possible to **Loop** over the a "field" [text list] for condition (if found "**SE**") value than just redo other calculation on the page.

**New Update item: on 10/07/2019**

Formula to extract the orignal value and replace value

```
FullSummary := @Trim(@Replace("SE" + @Right(InvGSTSummary; "SE"); "SE"; ""));
STCode := @Word(FullSummary; ","; 1);
Price := @Word(FullSummary; ","; 2);
SST:=@TextToNumber(Price) * 0.06;

CompVal:= STCode +","+Price+","+@Text(SST; "F2");

CompVal
```

**Result of the formula:**
[image: after extract value]

Comment: Where does the 6% come from? The line still starts with SE 0%... And will your code be used in a country with the comma as decimal separator?

Comment: the comma "," came from another formula (use dbcolumn and dblookup) in order to get the value, but customer want me to speciallly (count 6 % to SE(special request) which originally is 0%  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get field's entry you want to change,
2. Calculate entry's new value,
3. Replace entry in field.

Example for replacing entry that starts with "SE":

```
_entryOld := @Trim(@Replace("SE" + @Right(InvGSTSummary; "SE"); "SE"; ""));
_entryNew := @Word(_entryOld; ","; 1) + ... calculate your new value based on _entryOld;
@Replace(InvGSTSummary; _entryOld, _entryNew);
```

Here is an alternative for the "loop" to get the entry with "SE":

```
_entryOld := @Trim(@Transform(InvGSTSummary; "entry"; 
                              @If(@Contains(entry; "SE"); entry; "")));
```

*Update to your updated question:*

Use @Replace in last code line to replace the old entry (FullSummary) with the new value (CompVal):

```
FullSummary := @Trim(@Replace("SE" + @Right(InvGSTSummary; "SE"); "SE"; ""));
STCode := @Word(FullSummary; ","; 1);
Price := @Word(FullSummary; ","; 2);
SST:=@TextToNumber(Price) * 0.06;

CompVal:= STCode +","+Price+","+@Text(SST; "F2");

@Replace(InvGSTSummary; FullSummary, CompVal);
```

Comment: May i know how to loop over Text list value, if found SE = do calculation , than replace "SE" line value

Comment: i saw replacement value, but the "loop" through 3 value, i don't understand how to write it

Comment: The first line does the loop. It replaces all entries that don't contain "SE" with an empty string "" and @Trim eliminates all empty entries. This way only the "SE" entry remains in _entryOld. I know it is a bit tricky to understand.