# Crystal report : How to Remove a value and replace a new value

Tags: crystal-reports, lotus-formula

Continuous question from previous topic but using different Software

[Lotus Notes : How to Remove a value and replace a new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896485/lotus-notes-how-to-remove-a-value-and-replace-a-new-value)

Lotus notes calculation for a field :

Value for InvGstSummary:

"- 0%,4000.00,0.00"

"SE 0%,4000.00,240.00"

"ST 6%,2000.00,120.00"

**Question is : How to write the formula in crystal report?**

Value : 
**"SE 0%,4000.00,240.00"**

Notes Formula:

```
FullSummary := @Trim(@Replace("SE" + @Right(InvGSTSummary; "SE"); "SE"; ""));
```

**Crystal report formula :
?**

Comment: Why don't you calculate values in Notes and send those values to Crystal report?

Comment: can , but need to add extra field again for a field to keep the data, and crystal report also need verify the database to updated it, if use crystal report function (right function)  doesn't have same feature.